# How can I multiply an additively homomorphic encrypted value by a float number?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

As we all know, if $E()$ is an additively homomorphic encryption, we can multiply $E(a)$ by an integer $b$, then we will get $E(ab)$. But what if $a$ is a float number? Can we still get $E(ab)$? Which scheme can support this?

Comment: The thing I want is to multiply $a$ by a value $b$ which is smaller than 1, so that to reduce $a$ without using subtraction.

Comment: I don't know of any cryptographic algorithm, which works with floating point numbers.

Comment: Fully homomorphic encryption may be able to deal with floating point numbers (using some fancy combination of integer multiplications and additions). Standard schemes (Paillier, ElGamal, RSA, ...) can only deal with integer arithmetic.

Comment: Fully homomophic encryption will be able to deal with floating point (as they can perform any algorithm that runs in bounded time); however it's likely to be expensive.

Comment: I haven't come across any work using floating point with homomorphic encryption (partial or fully). There have been some papers discussing how to do secure multiparty computation with floating point values (see [ePrint](https://eprint.iacr.org/eprint-bin/search.pl?titlewords=floating)).

Comment: One would look into a subset of rational numbers of bounded numerator and demoninator. Not exactly float, still might be usable.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych Could you give more explanations, or could you give an example?

Comment: For example, let $n$ and $d$ be two integers approximating a rational $f$. That is, $\frac{n}{d} \approx f$. Both $n$ and $d$ could be encrypted with Paillier scheme if $n < N$ and $d < N$ for modulus $N^2$.